# How to limit SQL Server query to single table partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-partitioning

I want to query a massive table, and need to get my query runtime down.

I'm trying to breakup my target query, into many steps, by running my summarizing query against each individual table partition (I will then aggregate the outputs). All the columns in my where clauses are indexed (nonclustered) -- all the columns I'm pulling in my query are indexed. The "Month" column is our partition index.

How do I write my query, so that I'm explicitly telling SQL Server to only use one "Month" partition?

edit to include Execution plan:
  Per the comment, used this site: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJRAIUD3V

Comment: Are you sure the optimizer isn't doing this for you? Do you have a current problem, or are you preemptively optimizing? Pasting your execution via [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) would help.

Comment: @scsimon, not at all.  I assumed that having my where clause include: "Where month = my_month" would tell it to do so.  But, my performance is still so bad I'm suspecting it's not doing that correctly.  Full table (all partitions is 280M rows); it has roughly 14 partitions.  Our database normally powers through tables with 20M rows (the "per partition" equivalent) quite quickly.  This has run for 30 minutes now.

Comment: So it's running for a long time, but you don't know *why*. There could be blocking, memory pressure, CPU pressure, a host of other things. [Here is a quick blog](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) on getting help with that. One output I'd like to see in addition is [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) to check for blocking and other contention.

Comment: For `sp_whoisactive`, here are some parameters that'd help in this case (personal preference here...) `exec sp_WhoIsActive 
   @show_sleeping_spids = 1
   ,@get_full_inner_text = 1
   ,@get_outer_command = 1
   ,@get_additional_info = 1
   ,@find_block_leaders = 1
   ,@get_avg_time = 1
   ,@get_transaction_info = 1`

Comment: Ah - I don't have sp_whoisactive privileges.  FWIW: my indexes are all partitioned indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have read the suggestions and still want to use partitions the query would be as follows once you have portioned the table with Month as the key_column.

```
SELECT <Your_select_list>
FROM <dbo.partitioned_table>
WHERE key_column = <target_month>
```